# How to get my own ICultureSelector implementation injected in the framework

Tags: localization, orchardcms

I have implemented my version of ICultureSelector, in a custom module.
Here it is a part of its definition (my question is not about the logic to select the culture; I tried with my own namespace and also with a namespace same as the namespace used in the module Orchard.Localization):

```
namespace Orchard.Localization.Selectors
{
    [OrchardFeature("Orchard.Localization.CultureSelector")]
    public class ShortRouteCultureSelector : ICultureSelector
    {
        public CultureSelectorResult GetCulture(HttpContextBase context)
        {
            ...
```

I put a breakpoint in the method GetCurrentCulture of the class CurrentCultureWorkContext in the Orchard.Framework project, and I see that the variable IEnumerable _cultureSelectors contains all the implementation of ICultureSelector of the module Orchard.Localization but not my implementation, that is never used.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to remove the `OrchardFeature` attribute or define your own feature name as `Orchard.Localization.CultureSelector` is defined in `Orchard.Localization` module already.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy It works! I thought that the dependency injection uses this attribute to consider my implementation together the other. If you write this as an answer I could accept it because you solved my problem

Comment: Glad i could help, answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `OrchardFeature` attribute or define your own feature name as `Orchard.Localization.CultureSelector` is defined in `Orchard.Localization` module already.